# What is the inverse of the function $f\colon (-1, 1)\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found the inverse to be $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}$, and thought if was an easy problem. It was pointed out to me that (1) this isn't one function because of the $\pm$ and (2) the function has to have $f^{-1}(0)=0$ and my forumula doesn't work for $0$.

The correct formula for the inverse is actually $$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{2x}{1+\sqrt{1+4x^2}}.$$

My question: Will someone please explain how to find this correct formula for $f^{-1}$?

Edit: I've edited the question to remove a mistake concerning the range of $f$.

Comment: note:  $f(0.8)\not\in(-1,1)$

Comment: Thanks, @J.W.Tanner, for pointing that out. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $y=f(x)$. Then $(1-x^2)y=x$, and since $x\in(-1,1)$, $1-x^2>0$, so $x$ and $y$ have the same sign.

We have $x^2y+x-1$ so if $y\neq 0$, then $x=\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y}$. But in order to ensure $x$ and $y$ have the same sign, we require the $\pm$ to be a plus.

Therefore, $f^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}=\dfrac{2x}{1+\sqrt{1+4x^2}}$ . (This can be seen by multiplying by $\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{1+\sqrt{1+4x^2}}$.) Since $f^{-1}(0)=0$, this also holds for $x=0$.

Comment: Very clear and helpful. Thanks.